# This is a Python code to get a md5 digest of a signature, Need help to implement this thing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, cryptography, md5, digital-signature

Python Code that works fine and I checked this Python code for message "a" it gives me the result "52F17E7031982DE1744A57F6EE9BD3A3"

```
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256, MD5
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5
from OpenSSL import crypto


message = "a".encode('utf-8')
p12 = crypto.load_pkcs12(company_p12_certificate, certificate_password)
key_bytes = crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_privatekey())

key = RSA.import_key(key_bytes)


h = SHA256.new(message)
signer = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)

signature = signer.sign(h)
md5_digest = MD5.new(signature)

result = str(md5_digest.digest().hex()).upper()
```

I implemented this using JavaScript but not getting same result. It gives me "4EB5DB7F5459E832DE3E0638A8F4C4A0" for message "a"
My JavaScript code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function _privateKeyToPkcs8(privateKey) {
    var rsaPrivateKey = forge.pki.privateKeyToAsn1(privateKey);
    var privateKeyInfo = forge.pki.wrapRsaPrivateKey(rsaPrivateKey);
    var privateKeyInfoDer = forge.asn1.toDer(privateKeyInfo).getBytes();
    var privateKeyInfoDerBuff = stringToArrayBuffer(privateKeyInfoDer);
    return privateKeyInfoDerBuff;
}
function stringToArrayBuffer(data) {
    var arrBuff = new ArrayBuffer(data.length);
    var writer = new Uint8Array(arrBuff);
    for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
        writer[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return arrBuff;
}

function arrayBufferToString(buffer) {
    var binary = '';
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    var len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
    }
    return binary;
}


$("#file").change(function () {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var contents = e.target.result;
        var pkcs12Der = arrayBufferToString(contents)
        var pkcs12B64 = forge.util.encode64(pkcs12Der);
        var pkcs12Der = forge.util.decode64(pkcs12B64);
        var pkcs12Asn1 = forge.asn1.fromDer(pkcs12Der);
        var pkcs12 = forge.pkcs12.pkcs12FromAsn1(pkcs12Asn1, false, '123456');
        var privateKey
        for (var sci = 0; sci < pkcs12.safeContents.length; ++sci) {
            var safeContents = pkcs12.safeContents[sci];

            for (var sbi = 0; sbi < safeContents.safeBags.length; ++sbi) {
                var safeBag = safeContents.safeBags[sbi];
                // this bag has a private key
                if (safeBag.type === forge.pki.oids.keyBag) {
                    //Found plain private key
                    privateKey = safeBag.key;
                } else if (safeBag.type === forge.pki.oids.pkcs8ShroudedKeyBag) {
                    // found encrypted private key
                    privateKey = safeBag.key;
                } else if (safeBag.type === forge.pki.oids.certBag) {
                    // this bag has a certificate...        
                }
            }
        }

        var privateKeyInfoDerBuff = _privateKeyToPkcs8(privateKey);

        //Import the webcrypto key
        crypto.subtle.importKey(
            'pkcs8',
            privateKeyInfoDerBuff,
            { name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5", hash: { name: "SHA-256" } },
            true,
            ["sign"]).
            then(function (cryptoKey) {
                var sha256 = forge.md.sha256.create();
                sha256.update('a');  // Message will come here

                var digestToSignBuf = stringToArrayBuffer(sha256.digest().toHex());

                crypto.subtle.sign({ name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5" }, cryptoKey, digestToSignBuf)
                    .then(function (signature) {
                        var signatureB64 = forge.util.encode64(arrayBufferToString(signature))
                        var md5 = forge.md.md5.create();
                        md5.update(signatureB64);
                        console.log("final result", md5.digest().toHex().toUpperCase());
                    });
            })
    }
})
});
```

I also checked https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge

Comment: Is content of `signature` in Python and `signatureB64` in JS the same? `signature` is binary string, and maybe this isn't base64 at all, but binary data? Also your message in Python is not "a" but "message".

Comment: In python signature content is : b'\x8a\xaf\x95@\'\xe4\x8c\x03\xc0\xbc(_\x8a\x1a\x9eM\xe0\xe7\x11\x8e\x10\xb5Xkq\x8cW\xb5\xa0\xe8/\x8cn\xd2\xe9X\xd7|\x9c\xff\xe042s\xad\xb9yB\xbcaGq%\xfb#\xb8\xebQ_\x87\xeb\xa1\xa8!w\xe7\xa4\x88\xdb\x8bt\x14m{\x05\x187\x80\xfc\xf0\xea\x1a\xa9\xb9O\xa9G\xbc\x84\xe4\x10\x17\xa5\xc8&\x12Igs\xe9\xea\x1a~&\xb4\xa5>N9\x8d\\DL\xa1$T\x90b\x90\xf6\xba\x1a\xeauPm\xcc5\xb8"\xa1\xdb\x7f\xb6\xe1\xeeo\x94P\x0bZ\xed]\x00\x13\x17z}\xc9\x10\xaf\x8c\xcen*Wq\xbewDhr\xd8:)\x99\xae!......so on

Comment: And Js signatureB64 is : p/6wag0/ktZ5y02dspkLuSqVoq3Oe9S78qPap3fWbluB5x8D5VzaQLd62X5NISji65hI9X9rmy4BvbspwmscxYwV3MXcZZ/Ve/NQo3c4PT1x5rktma8u2BUZkgkHdjdGOh56CkDk8cgqzfRzRBRgRaWzTb3cvWZ/earZLRmBPoHUP2cGbth2a4e0xbgcXJcjpn1RfXx3KXYgC7zp1vJpNESzAOjlRfbTamHOgQ+JYEtGziOWlgJgQynbwhz/Jl5bw0/kJ8n3SVpy09SJ8sIIcuDgnf1r6XC9SBUtobGVfIczo4QTPzXN5dLzcwTEVKyMesTMiiZfQ/GoF0/uI2ZTDQ==

Comment: Hashing the signature makes it impossible to verify it.

Comment: Then how to implement in Js to get the same value as python? Because it is required.  OK we can change the Python to give result as Js. Means I want same output on both side.

Comment: `var digestToSignBuf = ...` uses the hex encoded SHA256 hash for signing (presumably the _raw_ hash should be used instead). `var signatureB64 = ...` performs a Base64 encoding of the signature, from which the MD5 hash is then created (presumably the _raw_ signature should be hashed instead).

Comment: Sorry @ user 9014097  don't understand you point!

Comment: `toHex()` presumably creates a hex encoded SHA256 hash (I don't see this in the Python code). `encode64()` presumably performs a Base64 encoding of the signature (I don't see this in the Python code either). Also, President James K. Polk is right, verification with the public key is not possible because of the MD5 hash (but maybe you don't intend that).

Comment: @ user 9014097 verification is not needed only I want same output on both side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*WebCrypto* implicitly generates the hash of the data during signing using the digest SHA-256 specified in the key, so explicit hashing with SHA-256 is not necessary.
Also, the generated signature is directly hashed with MD5, i.e. without prior Base64 encoding.

With these changes, the JavaScript code is (using a test key):

```js
// Import private test key
var pkcs8pem = `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
                MIIBVQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAT8wggE7AgEAAkEA2gdsVIRmg5IH0rG3
                u3w+gHCZq5o4OMQIeomC1NTeHgxbkrfznv7TgWVzrHpr3HHK8IpLlG04/aBo6U5W
                2umHQQIDAQABAkEAu7wulGvZFat1Xv+19BMcgl3yhCdsB70Mi+7CH98XTwjACk4T
                +IYv4N53j16gce7U5fJxmGkdq83+xAyeyw8U0QIhAPIMhbtXlRS7XpkB66l5DvN1
                XrKRWeB3RtvcUSf30RyFAiEA5ph7eWXbXWpIhdWMoe50yffF7pW+C5z07tzAIH6D
                Ko0CIQCyveSTr917bdIxk2V/xNHxnx7LJuMEC5DcExorNanKMQIgUxHRQU1hNgjI
                sXXZoKgfaHaa1jUZbmOPlNDvYYVRyS0CIB9ZZee2zubyRla4qN8PQxCJb7DiICmH
                7nWP7CIvcQwB
                -----END PRIVATE KEY-----`;

var pkcs8 = convertDER(pkcs8pem);

crypto.subtle.importKey(
    'pkcs8',
    pkcs8,
    { name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5", hash: { name: "SHA-256" } },
    true,
    ["sign"])
.then(function (cryptoKey) {
      
    // Sign message
    var message = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
    crypto.subtle.sign(
        { name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5" }, 
        cryptoKey, 
        stringToArrayBuffer(message))
    .then(function (signature) {
        
        // Create MD5 hash
        var md5 = forge.md.md5.create();
        md5.update(arrayBufferToString(signature));
        console.log("Final result", md5.digest().toHex().toUpperCase()); // Final result 30FD001CFD12D0A3DF000D216C82C47E
    });
}); 

// Helper
function stringToArrayBuffer(data) {
    var arrBuff = new ArrayBuffer(data.length);
    var writer = new Uint8Array(arrBuff);
    for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
        writer[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return arrBuff;
}   

function arrayBufferToString(buffer) {
    var binary = '';
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    var len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
    }
    return binary;
}   

function convertDER(pem){
    var pemHeader = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----";
    var pemFooter = "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
    var pemContents = pkcs8pem.substring(pemHeader.length, pkcs8pem.length - pemFooter.length);
    var binaryDerString = window.atob(pemContents);
    var pkcs8 = stringToArrayBuffer(binaryDerString);
    return pkcs8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/forge/0.10.0/forge.min.js"></script>
```

with the output:

```
Final result 30FD001CFD12D0A3DF000D216C82C47E
```

The Python code returns the same result for the same key and plaintext.

```py
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256, MD5
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5

key_bytes = '''-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBVQI...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----'''

message = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".encode('utf-8')
key = RSA.import_key(key_bytes)

h = SHA256.new(message)
signer = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)

signature = signer.sign(h)
md5_digest = MD5.new(signature)

result = str(md5_digest.digest().hex()).upper()
print(result) # 30FD001CFD12D0A3DF000D216C82C47E
```

---

As already noted in the comments, due to the MD5 hash, verification using the public key is not possible (but apparently not intended).

Also, *WebCrypto* provides the `SubtleCrypto.digest()` function to determine a hash, so the *forge* library is actually not really necessary (at least for hashing).

I've not analyzed the key import in more detail, so there may be problems here as well.